# The output doesn't appear while debugging in c in visual studio code

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code version 1.64.1 when I run a c program I see the output and everything works correctly but when I use the debugger no output appear and it doesn't ask me to enter a value to the variable age. and if I use python debugger everything works correctly too

[image]

Comment: Maybe `printf("Enter your age: "); fflush(stdout);` ?

Comment: sorry I didn't get that but when I run the program it work correctly ant the output appears then when I run it with debugging there is no output

Comment: Try entering an age anyway even with the blank screen. Just type `42<ENTER>` and see if anything happens

Comment: I tried but the terminal doesn't accept anything to be written I also tried to assign the age to the variable and don't use scanf function and that didn't work too.

Comment: Oh, good testing. Can't help you any further. Must be a Visual Studio thing. Your code is 99% ok (check the return value of `scanf()` for the extra point). Unrelated: stop using `scanf()` and use `fgets()` instead for more than 100% :-)

Comment: thanks for the advice and for visual studio I searched on youtube and did exactly the same as the video but it didn't work too although it worked in the video.